# Getting clang/llvm to use crle paths on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, llvm, clang, openindiana

I'm trying to configure an OpenIndiana build machine, and I'm new in general to the (not-so-) subtle differences in how (Open)(Solaris|Indiana) treat the build process. While I now understand that on Solaris, the default even when running on a 64-bit kernel is to build applications as m32, unless `-m64` is explicitly provided; I cannot seem to properly configure default search paths for `clang`, though `gcc` is working just fine and dandy.

I installed both `llvm` and `gcc` via `pkg`, nothing had to be manually compiled.

Compiling a basic C file with `gcc` works fine in both the default (`-m32`) and the 64-bit `-m64` configurations, correctly using the search paths as set in `crle`:

```
mqudsi@openindiana:~/random$ crle

Default configuration file (/var/ld/ld.config) not found
  Platform:     32-bit LSB 80386
  Default Library Path (ELF):   /lib:/usr/lib  (system default)
  Trusted Directories (ELF):    /lib/secure:/usr/lib/secure  (system default)
mqudsi@openindiana:~/random$ crle -64

Default configuration file (/var/ld/64/ld.config) not found
  Platform:     64-bit LSB AMD64
  Default Library Path (ELF):   /lib/64:/usr/lib/64  (system default)
  Trusted Directories (ELF):    /lib/secure/64:/usr/lib/secure/64  (system default)
```

However, `clang` seems to be oblivious to the system configuration, and is requiring me to manually set `-L ....` when compiling. Globally setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` fails because clang itself is 32-bit when trying to compile a 64-bit binary with it.

How can I get clang to respect the Solaris `crle` configuration in the same way that gcc does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, given that clang known a little about Solaris in general, the answer is easy, unfortunately: someone should implement crle support in clang.